# Problems initialising Django 1.8 app using apache 2.4 mod_passenger 5.0 after centos 7 yum update

Tags: django, apache, python-2.7, passenger, centos7

I have been ussing apache/mod_passenger on Centos 7 for a year now on my server at home to run a basic Django 1.8 app.
No issues, install updates with yum, etc.

Until today, I have noticed the website of my application was throwing an error. In the apache log I can see this:

```
[ 2016-02-21 19:45:38.8531 15680/7f470c08e880 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:707 ]: Passenger core online, PID 15680
[ 2016-02-21 19:45:38.8584 15685/7f6eda27f880 age/Ust/UstRouterMain.cpp:504 ]: Starting Passenger UstRouter...
[ 2016-02-21 19:45:38.8591 15685/7f6eda27f880 age/Ust/UstRouterMain.cpp:317 ]: Passenger UstRouter online, PID 15685
[Sun Feb 21 19:45:38.865561 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 15644] AH00163: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) OpenSSL/1.0.1e-fips mod_fcgid/2.3.9 Phusion_Passenger/5.0.25 mod_wsgi/3.4 Python/2.7.5 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Feb 21 19:45:38.865602 2016] [core:notice] [pid 15644] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'
[Sun Feb 21 19:46:58.467864 2016] [autoindex:error] [pid 15701] [client 86.121.21.124:64572] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /var/www/myProjects/testuser66/static/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.html) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive
App 15712 stdout:
App 15712 stderr: error: cannot open Packages index using db5 - Permission denied (13)
App 15712 stderr: error: cannot open Packages database in /var/lib/rpm
App 15712 stderr: Traceback (most recent call last):
App 15712 stderr:   File "/usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/wsgi-loader.py", line 325, in <module>
App 15712 stderr:     app_module = load_app()
App 15712 stderr:   File "/usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/wsgi-loader.py", line 62, in load_app
App 15712 stderr:
App 15712 stderr: return imp.load_source('passenger_wsgi', startup_file)
App 15712 stderr:   File "/var/www/myProjects/testuser66/passenger_wsgi.py", line 8, in <module>
App 15712 stderr:     if sys.executable != INTERP: os.execl(INTERP, INTERP, *sys.argv)
App 15712 stderr:   File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/os.py", line 312, in execl
App 15712 stderr:     execv(file, args)
App 15712 stderr: OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied
App 15712 stderr:
[ 2016-02-21 19:47:02.9959 15680/7f470bef7700 age/Cor/App/Implementation.cpp:304 ]: Could not spawn process for application /var/www/myProjects/testuser66: An error occurred while starting the web application. It exited before signalling successful startup back to Phusion Passenger.
Error ID: d7ea712a
Error details saved to: /tmp/passenger-error-kqxLLO.html
Message from application: An error occurred while starting the web application. It exited before signalling successful startup back to Phusion Passenger. Please read <a href="https://github.com/phusion/passenger/wiki/Debugging-application-startup-problems">this article</a> for more information about this problem.<br>
```

### Raw process output:

```
error: cannot open Packages index using db5 - Permission denied (13)
error: cannot open Packages database in /var/lib/rpm
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/wsgi-loader.py", line 325, in <module>
   app_module = load_app()
 File "/usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/wsgi-loader.py", line 62, in load_app
   return imp.load_source('passenger_wsgi', startup_file)
 File "/var/www/myProjects/testuser66/passenger_wsgi.py", line 8, in <module>
   if sys.executable != INTERP: os.execl(INTERP, INTERP, *sys.argv)
 File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/os.py", line 312, in execl
   execv(file, args)
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

```
[ 2016-02-21 19:47:02.9999 15680/7f4706242700 age/Cor/Con/CheckoutSession.cpp:277 ]: [Client 1-1] Cannot checkout session because a spawning error occurred. The identifier of the error is d7ea712a. Please see earlier logs for details about the error.
```

I used to have some trouble with Passenger after running yum update, but usually because of SE Linux. But I have checked permissions to my best knowledge and it is not the case.

Also the "cannot open /var/lib/rpm" is confusiog for me. What does it have to do with Apache/Passenger? I checked the rpm db, deleted yum cache, there are no signs of corupted rpm db.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: If sudoers is installed then use command `sudo yum update` or change user to root.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the sugestion, of course I used sudo. I was having trouble in the past with SE Linux, but I checked the permissions and selinux flags and everything looks alright. I will try to have a look into this over the weekend.

Comment: I just kept using apache mod_wsgi on my live server.
However last week after running an update on my centos7 box, I noticed Apache/Passenger started serving again the old websites.

I will take this opportunity and try a new deployment, and check all steps.
Installing and configuring with SEL enabled was a challenge, I guess I will use docker images from now on. :-p